# Convex hull of $\exp\bigl( \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb R)\bigr)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

> What is the convex hull of  $\exp\bigl( \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb R)\bigr)$ ?

My attempt :

> **lemma** For $A\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb C)$ there exist $P(X)\in \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $A=\exp{P(A)}$

*Proof.* Let $A=DU$ with $D$ diagonalizable and $U$ unipotent, there exist $Q(X)\in \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $D=\exp{Q(D)}$ and $U=\exp( \log(U)) $. AS $Q(D)$ et $\log(U)$ commute we have $A=\exp\bigl(Q(D)+log(U)\bigr)$. Now the result follow because $D$ and $U$ are polynomial in $A$

> **Claim.** $\exp\bigl( \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb R)\bigr)=\bigl( \mathcal{GL}_n(\mathbb R)\bigr)^2$

*Proof.* Using the lemma we have for $A\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb R)$, there exist $P(X)\in \mathbb{C}[X]$ such that $A=\exp\bigl(P(A)\bigr)$. Then $A^2=\exp\bigl(P(A)+\overline{P(A)}\bigr)$ with $P(A)+\overline{P(A)}\in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb R)$.$\square$

Unfortunately I don't know if that help. How can I continue ?

Comment: so, what is $P(X)$ when $A = 0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=1$, the result is clearly just $(0,\infty)$. So suppose that $n\ge 2$.
If $E_{i,j}$ is the matric with $1$ at position $(i,j)$ and $0$ otherwise, we have $$\tag1\exp(t E_{i,j})=1+tE_{i,j}$$ (if $i\ne j$). This allows us to produce any matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal as convex combination of exponentials. Moreover $$\tag2\exp(t E_{i,i})=1+(e^t-1)E_{i,i},$$ so that we can obtain all matrices with positive diagonal entries as convex combinations.
Finally 
$$\tag3\exp(\pi E_{i,j}-\pi E_{j,i}+uE_{i,i}+u E_{j,j})=1-e^u(E_{i,i}+E_{j,j}). $$
From matrices of the form $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$, you can obtain any matrix in $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ as convex combination.